# Am I able to open all the doors on a data vault?

Tags: x4-foundations

I've already picked up the timeline piece and a container, but 3 of the cargo areas remain closed.  I combed the entire thing up and down and I can't seem to find another switch in order to open the remaining doors.  Is this intentional or did I miss something?

[image: How do I open these?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing through the game some more and opening all the vaults, it seems that no, not every door on a vault can be opened.

Each vault will have 1 leak (for the timeline) and 1-2 containers.  Once that's collected the vault is complete.